# Exception while setting UIFont systemFont as Regular

Tags: ios, swift, uifont

I am getting the following exception when the app tries to set the font system font to UIBarButtonItem appearance during the app launch.

```
UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
```

I had the issue only the first time usage of systemFont successive usage doesn't raise any exception.

[image]

Comment: This was helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29874633/4139760